# Catch if the Java process crashed

Tags: java, process, crash, ffmpeg

I run java process to convert video using ffmpeg.exe.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String cmd = FFMPEGFULLPATH + " -y -i " + '"' + mpeg4File + '"' + " -vcodec libx264 -vsync 2 " + '"' + H264file + '"';

Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);

ThreadedTranscoderIO errorHandler = new ThreadedTranscoderIO(pr.getErrorStream(), "Error Stream");
errorHandler.start();
ThreadedTranscoderIO inputHandler = new ThreadedTranscoderIO(pr.getInputStream(), "Output Stream");
inputHandler.start();

try {
      pr.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
      LiveApplication.logger.info("Some shit happens during convertation 2 ");
      throw new IOException("UseTranscoderBlocking - Run_FFMPEG - process interrupted " + e);                  
}
```

But when the process started, sometimes especially with big files, but not always i get this windows message:

[image]

This happens only on Windows server 2008 and didn't happened on Windows 7.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why this process fails?
2. Can I catch this fail in Java, close
   this window and continue thread execution (maybe I'll restart this
   proccess).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the return value from [Process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29).  If the process crashes, it might return a distinct error code (possibly negative).

See [here](http://meta-coding.blogspot.com/2011/04/process-exit-code-after-crash.html) for some examples of how the exit code is affected by crashes on different OSes.